# Why DiskLruImageCache blocks I/O

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

`DiskLruImageCache`

The `DiskLruImageCache` is a wrapper for the `DiskLruCache` with a bitmap-centered implementation. It adds and retrieves the bitmaps from the `DiskLruCache`, and handles the cache instantiation. A disk cache may block I/O.

I was reading this article [from this blog](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/raymond-robinson/google-io-2013-volley-image-cache-tutorial)

Why do they not mention that disk cache may block I/O?

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about it.

They don't mention it since `DiskLruImageCache` and `DiskLruCache` **have nothing to do with Volley**. These are projects by Jake Wharton which are available on GitHub.

It seems that the author of the blog you read decided to switch Volley's disk cache (`DiskBasedCache`) with Jake's.

You really don't have to do what he did. Volley's disk cache works fine.